# Get the length of an object if the object's type is a collection or any kind

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

So basically, I have a method that takes a parameter of type object. In case that object is in fact a List, or an array or a collection of any kind, I need to get the number of elements it contains.

I can check if it is an array but checking the IsArray property on the type and then casting the object to an Array, but how do I check for other collections?

Testing shows that List will cast to ICollection, but I don't know how to check it the object is in fact a List of any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the object is `IEnumerable` and if it is, use the Extension method for  `IEnumerable<T>`

```
IEnumerable e = obj as IEnumerable;
if (e != null)
   count = e.Cast<object>.Count();
```

Comment: ICollection ended up being enough in my case, but this answer actually solves the posted problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but all arrays and collections are enumerable:

```
var enumerableObj = obj as IEnumerable;
if(enumerableObj != null)
{
    var count = enumerableObj.Count();

    .....

}
```

Comment: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx doesn't have Count().

Comment: In a way, it does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/scekt9xw.aspx) keyword which can be used to type check. You can type check for `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, `IList` etc.. Example below.

```
var obj = new List<int>();

if (obj is IList)//True
    var count = ((IList)obj).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can check that your type is some kind of collection using the Type.IsAssignableFrom method.

```
typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(yourType)
```